# Bitmap.getPixel only returning 0

Tags: android

I have the following code for creating a bitmap:

```
public PixelMapper(Path inputPath){
    RectF src = new RectF();
    inputPath.computeBounds(src, true);
    int width = (int)src.width()+1;
    int height = (int)src.height()+1;
    largeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

    Paint canvasPaint = new Paint();
    canvasPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    canvasPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvasPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    canvasPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(largeBitmap);
    canvas.drawPath(inputPath, canvasPaint);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, SIDE_OF_BITMAP, SIDE_OF_BITMAP, true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);//so that a immutable bitmap is created
    drawPixelMap();
}

public void drawPixelMap(){
    for(int x=0; x<bitmap.getWidth(); x++){
        String msg="";
        for(int y=0; y<bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
            msg = Integer.toHexString( bitmap.getPixel(x,y) );
            Log.v("bitmap", msg);   
        }           
    }
}

int[] pixels = new int[64]; 
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, SIDE_OF_BITMAP, SIDE_OF_BITMAP);
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 8, 0, 0, 8, 8);
for ( int pixel : pixels)
    Log.v("bitmap", Integer.toHexString(pixel) );
```

The problem is that all the log messages are "0": both getPixel and getPixels return "0". What is worse is that if I remove the line `bitmap.getPixels(...);` and leave the `bitmap.setPixels(...)` line,the image is still drawn as before. It seems that the `bitmap` variable is just a reference and a bitmap doesn't exist, and for some reason, I am unable to get those pixels.
I know the bitmap is created as required as I am able to view it on a `ImageView`. It shows black and white pixels with a few grey ones too. Code:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 128, 128, false);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

The `SIDE_OF_BITMAP = 8`, all classes (Path, Bitmap, Canvas) are of android.

I tried saving the bitmap to file with the following code:

```
public String saveToStorage(String fileName){
    if( !storageDir.exists() )
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(storageDir, fileName + ".png");
    try{
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        boolean result = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
        return Boolean.toString(result);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("save", "cannot save file", e);
        return "File not found exception";
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("save", "IO error", e);
        return "IO Exception";
    }
}
```

but it returns "false" i.e. the bitmap.compress method returns false. Please give me any help at all, not necessarily sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. It lies in the line

```
largeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
```

The `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8` only creates a mask. It does not create actual pixels. That is why I was getting the erroneous results. However, when I was setting it to a `ImageView` I was getting the required result because its background (by default) is white.
I solved my problem by changing the `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8` to `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`

Comment: BTW, It's ARGB_8888 not ARG_B8888.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
```

creates a immutable bitmap of the same dimension/color depth, etc as the source bitmap, but not converting the source bitmap from mutable to immutable. So your new bitmap is blank.

You can first create a immutable bitmap using `newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(int[], int, int, Bitmap.Config)`, then create a canvas for it by `canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap)`. Your bitmap can now be copied to `newBitmap` by `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null)`.

Comment: I have saved the newly created immutable bitmap back into the old reference (of "bitmap"). Moreover, If my new bitmap is blank, then how is it showing correctly on the ImageView? And was getting the same result without the statement altogether.

Comment: Anyway, I tried and got a fatal error: immutable bitmap sent to canvas for drawing. Then in a similar way I created a mutable bitmap and used Canvas.drawBitmap, but I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, Canvas requires mutable bitmap. Try using `Bitmap.createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap.Config)`. Can you show more code on how you display the problematic bitmap on an ImageView?

Comment: Yes I had used that one and uesd Canvas.drawBitmap but I still get the same problem.